# Copy Data Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, copy-paste, uipasteboard

How would I copy NSData file programmatically. I know to copy text it is very simple.

Example:

Objective-C:

```
UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pb setString:[textView text]];
```

How would I set it so that it copies an NSData value instead of a text. I am trying to copy an image.

Comment: Copy to `UIPasteboard `? or copy to disk?

Comment: Stringify your image and then read it back on the other end?

Comment: If you have a `UIImage`, use the `image` property of `UIPasteboard`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first convert NSData to NSString & then set to pasteBoard

```
 NSString* stringToPaste = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[YOUR_NSData bytes]];
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy image you can do this :

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"ImageName" ofType:@"png"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
[pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"imageName_public.png"];
```

To paste image can simply do this :

```
UIImage *img = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;
```